# Knockoutjs. How to compute data changed inside observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Please, look at my text. I try to use observableArray of knockoutjs and foreach to compute data of array. 
Example 1 works fine: total sum computed if you change data in the fields. But Example 2 is not working.

```
<html>
<head>                                                                         
    <title></title>                                                            
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>     
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js'></script> 
</head>                                                                        
<body>
<p>Example 1</p>
<div>
    <p>
    <input data-bind="value: fnum1" />
    <input data-bind="value: fnum2" />
    <span data-bind="text: ftotsum"></span>
    </p>
</div>    
<p>Example 2</p>
<div>
    <p>
    <!-- ko foreach: fields -->
    <input data-bind="value: $data" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <span data-bind="text: ltotsum"></span>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function vm(){
        //Calc Example 1
        var self = this;
        self.fnum1 = ko.observable(1);
        self.fnum2 = ko.observable(2);
        self.ftotsum = ko.computed(function(){
            return parseFloat(self.fnum1()) + parseFloat(self.fnum2());
        });
        //Calc Example 2
        self.fields = ko.observableArray([1, 2]);
        self.ltotsum = ko.computed(function(){
            var total = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.fields(), function(item) {
                total += parseFloat(item);
            })
            return total;
        }); 
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** Got fiddle working, Raffaele is correct in saying you need to wrap the observable inside an object, but you can do it within the array creation itself and I like to use the ko.utils to unwrap my observables, it does the same thing for observables but it won't crash if there is a non-observable passed to it. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rynan/EBxy4/) for full example.

An observableArray doesn't make the values passed observable, this is a common mistake. An observableArray just observes the modifications to the array and not the values. If you want to have your values inside your array be observable you have to make them so.

```
function vm(){
    //Calc Example 1
    var self = this;
    self.fnum1 = ko.observable(1);
    self.fnum2 = ko.observable(2);
    self.ftotsum = ko.computed(function(){
        return parseFloat(self.fnum1()) + parseFloat(self.fnum2());
    });
    //Calc Example 2
    self.fields = ko.observableArray([{"num":ko.observable(1)},{"num":ko.observable(2)}]);
    self.ltotsum = ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.fields(), function(item) {
            total += parseFloat(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.num));
        });
        return total;
    }); 
};
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Should work with the example above now.

Comment: However it's true that observableArray doesn't make the values passed observable, but your sample code is not working. E.g. in the line `total += parseFloat(item); ` the `item` should be `item()` ... and in it's current state it still not binds correctly and updates the UI if you try it out...

Comment: I just used the Posters code let me fiddle it and see if I can't get it working.

Comment: Fixed my answer, It's similar but still different from Raffaele's so I figured I would still post it.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) says:

> **Key point: An `observableArray` tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are **added** or
>   **removed**.

Your second example doesn't work because the value of the input fields **is not bound** to the values in the array. That values in the array are used only once, in the `foreach` binding, but when you type in the input boxes, nothing triggers KO.

Here is [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eysae/) with a solution implemented. I used a helper `ObsNumber`

```js
function vm(){
    var self = this;

    var ObsNumber = function(i) {
        this.value = ko.observable(i);
    }

    self.fields = ko.observableArray([new ObsNumber(1) ,
                                      new ObsNumber(2)]);

    self.sum = ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.fields(), function(item) {
            total += parseFloat(item.value());
        });
        return total;
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

and the following markup

```
<div>
    <p>
    <!-- ko foreach: fields -->
    <input data-bind="value: $data.value" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <span data-bind="text: sum"></span>
    </p>
</div>​
```

Comment: +1 You can also write in the template `data-bind="value: value"` and yes you need to wrap the observable into an object before putting them into the observableArray.